# Crear tarea mysql que se ejecute de manera automática todos los días a una hora determinada

Tags: mysql

miren pongo en contexto:

Tengo un sistema a base de membresías (cuentas), cada cuenta registra la fecha en la que se registró por ejemplo hoy: 2018-06-06.

Necesito:
1.- Obtener (a través de mysql) **el día** en que cada usuario se registró, en este caso el día 06.

2.- Hacer que Mysql ejecute una tarea diaria que afecte a todos los usuarios que tienen ese día de registro. Es decir, si la tarea se ejecuta el día 06 de Julio (del siguiente mes), afecte a todos usuarios que se registraron el día 06 de junio (los que se registraron el mes anterior). Y así sucesivamente.

Mi problema es que para hacer lo primero, necesito primero saber como ejecutar lo segundo. Es decir, ¿Lo que necesito lo puedo  hacer con un procedimiento almacenado? si es así, ¿Como hago para que ese procedimiento se ejecute diariamente (de manera automática) por ejemplo a las 00:00hrs de cada día.?

Gracias por su orientación.

Saludos desde ya.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo primero es habilitar a nuestro servidor MySQL para que pueda hacerlo, con la siguiente línea:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

y te pongo un ejemplo aunque te invito a que visites la documentacion de mysql donde te explican de manera mas extensa que puedes llegar a hacer.

```
CREATE EVENT `close_expired_membresia` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2018-01-01 00:00:01'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO update tabla
set valido = 0
where
DATE_ADD(fechaCreacion, INTERVAL 45 DAY)<NOW() and valido=1;
```

Comment: Alberto, gracias, pero precisamente necesito una pista para poder documentarme. ¿Eso que me acabas de compartir como se llama? ¿Evento?¿Tarea programada? ¿O como lo busco? Gracias.

Comment: https://donnierock.com/2013/01/30/eventos-en-mysql-planificar-tareas-fecha/ ahi tienes desarrollado lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, me sirvió de mucho tu ayuda. Saludos.